# "Possible duplicate" comment not added after closing as a duplicate from the android app

Tags: bug, comments, android-app

I just voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22693739/how-to-show-command-output-in-stdout-and-also-transfer-it-to-pipe) as a duplicate from the android app, and the `possible duplicate` comment never appeared.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is bug or not without more information... but if you voted as dupe as [crazycloud's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22693739/how-to-show-command-output-in-stdout-and-also-transfer-it-to-pipe#comment34576216_22693739), then "*Possible duplicate*" comment won't appear. The comment won't show if the link is already mentioned on the comment; it will be upvoted instead. Otherwise... it's a bug on app where it doesn't refresh the view after voting, or bug with API.

Comment: @AndrewT. That may be the case then. I think I voted to close with the same target that appeared in the first comment.